# Which definition of convergence of subsequence is correct

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence on a metric space $(M,d)$ with limit $x \in (M,d)$

Let $(x_{n_k})$ be the sub-sequence of the sequence $(x_n)$

Then is it more appropriate to write

1) $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$ if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n_k \geq N, d(x_{n_k}, x) < \epsilon$

or

2)  $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$ if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall k \geq N, d(x_{n_k}, x) < \epsilon$

Which one is correct and why

Comment: *Hint:* both are equivalent: try to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct since we assume $\{n_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers when defining $\{x_{n_k}\}$.

Comment: Since $\{n_k\}$ is an stricly increasing sequence of natural numbers we have $n_{k}\geq k$. By this fact it is easy to see (2) implies (1). how can we prove (1) implies (2)? I couldn't see it. Can you write explicitly, please?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_{n_k}\to x$ according to (1). Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n_k>N$ we have that $x_{n_k}\in B(x,\epsilon)$. So for every $k>N$ we have that $n_k>N$ (as $n_k\geq k$) and hence $x_{n_k}\in B(x,\epsilon)$. So we see that $x_{n_k}\to x$ according to (2).

Suppose $x_{n_k}\to x$ according to (2). Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $k>N$ we have that $x_{n_k}\in B(x,\epsilon)$. Let $N'=n_N$. Then for every $n_k>N'$ we have that $k>N$ (if $k\leq N$ then $n_k\leq n_N$) and hence $x_{n_k}\in B(x,\epsilon)$. So we see that $x_{n_k}\to x$ according to (1).

So we see that both (1) and (2) are equivalent and so both are correct. However, it is more appropriate to use (2). This is because we consider a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ to be the sequence whose $k^{th}$ term is $x_{n_k}$. In other words, suppose for every $k\in\mathbb N$ we let $y_k=x_{n_k}$ then the sequence $(y_k)$ is the same as the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$.